# Is it possible to target a child component of styled component from a library?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am using a `<Form/>` component from a component library. The form has a child component for the submit button.

```
const loginForm = [
  {
    label: "Username",
    required: true,
    type: "text"
  },
  {
    label: "Password",
    required: true,
    type: "password"
  }
]

<LoginForm
  width={{ xs: 12, md: 4 }} 
  autoComplete={false}
  buttonDisabled={buttonDisabled}
  buttonLabel="LOGIN"
  fields={loginForm}
  onChange={this.onChange}
  onSubmit={data => login({ variables: data })}
/>
```

which generates this html:

[image]

I am wanting to target the button to style it. Was hoping to do something like this:

```
const LoginForm = styled(Form)`
  Button_StyledButton{
    outline: black solid 10px;
  }
`
```

Essentially targeting the form and then the child button component.

Can this be done with styled components?

Comment: May i know which component library you are using?

Comment: Take a look on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713421/target-child-element-styled-components?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a publicly available one

Comment: @ArunYokesh I did see that post but that is a different use case. They are passing in the child component as a child. The difference here is the button element I am trying to target is generated by the parent form component.

Comment: Have you tried writing `const LoginForm = styled(Form)\` > Button_StyledButton ...`? Also, does the `Form` element use the `className` prop given to it?

Comment: @Tholle yes i have tried that, as I have it in my original post but to no avail. The button doesn't have a class `Button_StyledButton` but it does have that as a `data-id`. The class it is given is generated by styled components which is a random string of characters and changes on each build so can't rely on that.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's not a public library you're using, make sure your library avail you to pass `className` prop.

> The `styled` method works perfectly on all of your own or any
>   third-party components as well, as long as they pass the `className`
>   prop to their rendered sub-components, which should pass it too, and
>   so on. Ultimately, the `className` must be passed down the line to an
>   actual DOM node for the styling to take any effect.

If this condition is satisfied, you can take advantage of the `styled(LoginForm)` approach.

I don't know the DOM structure generated by your `LoginForm`, but you can effectively target the button by a normal css selector.

Let's assume the DOM structure is this:

```
<form>
  <label>...</label>
  <input .../>
  <label>...</label>
  <input .../>
  <button>...</button>
</form>
```

Then you can target this button in the styled-components's `styled` method like this:

```
const LoginForm = styled(Form)`
  button {
    outline: black solid 10px;
  }
`
```

The selector really depends on the DOM structure, you need to adjust that to your needs.

If the `className` prop is not passed down the component tree in library you're using, you need to provide a wrapper component:

```
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  button {
    outline: black solid 10px;
  }
`
<Wrapper>
  <LoginForm
    width={{ xs: 12, md: 4 }} 
    autoComplete={false}
    buttonDisabled={buttonDisabled}
    buttonLabel="LOGIN"
    fields={loginForm}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    onSubmit={data => login({ variables: data })}
  />
</Wrapper>
```

CodeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/2w3owyjy2n