# Styling a Router Link with styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router-dom, styled-components

What is the best way to style the Link using the styled-components library in the code that follows.
I can find lots of examples to work with anchor tag but none to work with react-router link.
Am I going about the correct way.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Nav = ({ className }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
export default styled(Nav)`
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  background: teal;
  width: 100%;
  ul {
    color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border: 1px solid green;
    list-style: none;
    li {
      padding: 15px 15px;
      border: 2px solid purple;
    }
  }
`;
```

Thanks
Joseph Shanahan

Answer (score 8):

Yes thanks for your help. A slimmed down version of what I will implement is as follows.
It also has the advantage in that I did not have to implement an unordered list.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Nav = ({ className }) => {
  return (
    <div className={className}>
      <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
    </div>
  );
};
const NavLink = styled(Link)`
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  &:hover {
    color: red;
    background: blue;
  }
`;
export default styled(Nav)`
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
`;
```

Thanks Joseph Shanahan

Answer (score 3):

You are in the right way, but little wrong, instead of using `ul` you just pass the component reference.

```
export default styled(Nav)`
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
  background: teal;
  width: 100%;
  ${Link} {
    /* style for Link Component */
  }
`;
```

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48713421/target-child-element-styled-components), it's very familiar.

Answer (score 0):

`react-router link` translates to after all in `<a>` tags so style them in the same way you would style an `<a>` tag 
so let's say, you need to change their color to red then:

```
ul {
    color: red;
}
```

won't work, you will need to do:

```
ul a {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to style the `Link` component, then the usual way in my experience is to create a styled component like so:

```
const NavLink = styled(Link)`
  /* Link styles */
`
```

And then just render it like `<NavLink>Home</NavLink>`.

This also makes it easy to reuse this styled component.

Answer (score -1):

const Nav = styled(Link)`your code here`;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).